# Running two Firefox instances: one normal and one Private Navigation

Tags: windows, linux, firefox

How do I run two concurrent Firefox instances of which one is a "regular" instance an the other is in "Private Navigation" mode?

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> my current instance closes.

I want both them opened. Internet Explorer does this by default.

Question is OS-agnostic

Comment: The best way to do this is with the shortcut arguments.

Comment: @Ramhound can you explain?

Comment: Explain how to use shortcuts to launch to two different profiles when Firefox is launched.  I have not used Firefox in years, when I did, I know what I describe was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible right now.
But they announced that they are going to implement this possiblity.

I look for some links and will add these if i find some.

### Edit

http://ehsanakhgari.org/blog/2012-11-30/per-window-private-browsing-ready-for-testing-now-2

this might be a nice way to have some functionallity you might wish when using firefox in private mode: http://www.callum-macdonald.com/about/faq/multiple-firefox-instances/

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to use pre-release software, the [Aurora](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/) and [Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) versions of Firefox support per-window private browsing. Aurora is the more stable of the two.

This feature will eventually make it into the released version of Firefox.

Otherwise, you may consider using [separate profiles](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) in conjunction with the `-no-remote` [command line switch](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile).

Comment: Just to add: "Private Browsing" is basically equal to having a separate profile which keeps no history, or discards all history when the browser is closed, something you can just set in the preferences.